# Set percentages of display cell color in the flexcpFloodPercent of C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Classic

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration, componentone

I am migrating a WinForms system from VB6 to VB.NET. I am using the C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Classic library from the Grapecity provider.

[image]

I want to set the color of the cell following the percentages of input.
I found the flexcpFloodPercent of cell property setting.

But when I applied flexcpFloodPercent to my flexGrid code I did not affect the color.
If You have experience working with this library, Could you please give me a sample to set the color of cells?

Comment: Add your code to the question